# django-admin: postgresql trigger function

Tags: postgresql, django

I have this table in django admin site the (Student_enrollment_record),
if i select an student and update/save the **Section** field

[image]

and it will search the **Section** field on what i select on the table  (Student_enrollment_record(**Section**)) in table (subject_section_teacher(**Section**))

[image]

and the result will automatically save here.

[image]

do i have to use an postgres trigger to solve my problem or should i use django_signals? Please provide an solution for my problem.